# How do I have multiple windows users (non-admins) modify and save the same setting(s)?

Tags: windows

Apologies if this is a really simple question...

We have a .NET application that is installed by an administrator, and then run by multiple staff on the same computer with their own login credentials (normal user - non-admin).

Application uses MSI installer and is installed to Program Files folder.

The application needs to have some settings about attached devices to the computer saved as preferences so when a user opens the app these settings are set and the user is not asked for preferences each time.  These preferences should not be set per user, rather per computer.

However if user A changes one of these settings on the computer, then when user B logs in they should see the changed setting from user A.
Hence the settings need to be per computer, not per user.

Where in windows 7,8,10 etc. can an application save data that is computer specific not user specific, yet allow users without admin rights to change that data?

We have looked at system temp folder but the computers have GPO policy to regularly remove temp folder content.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes administrator rights to change the permissions on a registry key inside HKLM, but once that's done, anyone in the group given permission can make modifications.

Obviously don't change permissions on any of the standard keys (e.g. `HKLM\Software` or `HKLM\Classes`) but in your own application area (`HKLM\Software\YouCorp\YouApp\Attached Devices`) it's perfectly fine to adjust permissions the way you like.

You'll just have to include "grant write permission on `HKLM\Software\YouCorp\YouApp\Attached Devices` to the group Users" as one of the actions of your installer.

If you are allergic to the registry, you can do the same with a subdirectory of your application install (e.g. `%ProgramFiles%\YouCorp\YouApp\Device Settings`)

Comment: Alternatively, use `%ProgramData%\Your_Organization\Your_Application`. Any user can create subdirectories of `%ProgramData%` and grant other users/groups access.

Comment: @eryksun: That's just not true.  The default permissions only allow administrators to make changes.  One of them (during install) has to grant write access to ordinary users.

Comment: You missed the fact that "BUILTIN\Users" is granted the right to create subdirectories of `%ProgramData%` and that there's a "CREATOR OWNER" ACE that grants all access to the user.

Comment: For reference, here's the [security descriptor](https://pastebin.com/kf7ZLSM0) on `%ProgramData%`, as listed by Sysinternals accesschk.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using a .Net application, you could store the information in the app.config file associated with the application.